# Ignoring text between parenthesis in Regex

Tags: java, regex

My goal is to read in the String and ignore the text in parenthesis.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern checkRegex= Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z]{3,30}\\s*){2}");
    
    Matcher regexMatcher=checkRegex.matcher("James Hunt(Skateboarder)");
    
    while(regexMatcher.find()){
    System.out.println(regexMatcher.group().trim());
}
```

The current output is:

> James Hunt
>
> Skateboarder

Essentially what I want is for the output to be only "James Hunt".
What is a suitable Regex pattern to use in this type of situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work for all non-nested parentheses in your given String:

```
String input = "James Hunt(Skateboarder)";
String output = input.replaceAll("\\([^)]*?\\)", "");
```

Answer (score 3):

> Essentially what I want is for the output to be only "James Hunt".
>   What is a suitable Regex pattern to use in this type of situation?

try regex: `^[^(]*`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to use regex you can get your data with one simple iteration

```
String data="some (sentence (with) nested) paranhesis";
StringBuilder buffer=new StringBuilder();
int parenthesisCounter=0;
for (char c:data.toCharArray()){
    if (c=='(') parenthesisCounter++;
    if (c==')') parenthesisCounter--;
    if (c!=')' && c!='(' && parenthesisCounter==0)
        buffer.append(c);
}
System.out.println(buffer);
```

output:

```
some  paranhesis
```

Comment: I agree, regex doesn't make sense in this situation. But the assignment asked for it...